Understanding the Approximation in Whitening for ICA
I’m currently studying Independent Component Analysis (ICA) and came across a particular approximation used in the FastICA algorithm that I’m struggling to fully understand. Specifically, it’s about the simplification involving whitening of the data. The text I’m referring to approximates the expectation as follows:
$E(xx^T g'(w^T x))$ ≈ $E(xx^T) E\{g{\prime}(w^T x)\} = E(g'(w^T x))I $
Here, ( x ) is the whitened data such that ( E($xx^T$) = I ). My understanding is that whitening transforms the data to have zero mean and unit covariance, thus removing linear correlations between the components.
However, I’m puzzled by this approximation because ( $xx^T$ ) and ( g’($w^T x$) ) involve the same random variable  x , which implies that they are not independent. Can anyone explain why this approximation is valid or under what conditions it holds true? How does whitening make this approximation reasonable despite the shared variable?
Thank you for your help!
